# how to decompress the filename.csv.Z file in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are having a **filename.csv.Z** file coming from the source(sftp server), we would need to unzip this file using Azure data factory and load into Azure SQL database. we have tried the compression type as "Zip Deflate" for the source(sftp) dataset but throwing us the below error

**“Can't find SFTP path 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.csv.Z'. Please check if the path exists. If the path you configured does not start with '/', note it is a relative path under the given user's default folder. No such file”**

Need help to decompress the `.Z` file in Azure data factory or by using power shell will also help.

Comment: Probably created using the "compress" command on Unix.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory only support **bzip2**, **gzip**, **deflate**, **ZipDeflate**, **snappy**, or **lz4** format compressed file.

[image]

Z file is not supported, we can not compress or decompress it.

For more details, please reference:

1. [Copy data from and to SFTP server using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp)
2. [Supported file formats and compression codecs in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs)

Hope this helps.